# Stronger Password-based File Encryption on OS X

Tags: encryption, macos, tools

I am wondering if there are any better alternatives than the `zip` command on the OS X terminal.

My intention is to add a password to a compressed file. I have been using:

`zip -j -e -pMY_SECRET test.zip example_file_pdf`

I have seen mentions of using the `7zip` ie:

`7za a -tzip -pMY_SECRET -mem=AES256 test.zip example_file.pdf`

But I don't believe this will work (or maybe I'm mistaken) on a OS X machine since there isn't a native port of it. Does anyone have any other ideas or recommendations?

**Edit:** I have found p7zip which is an ported version of 7zip to UNIX, OSX, etc... Is that something you guys typically recommend?

Comment: Please do some [basic searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=os+x+built+in+encryption) on your own and you will find lots of information. Apart from that use proper sources for your information and cite these, " I heard ..." is not really enough. And what has zip to do with encrypting passwords? What is your use case?

Comment: Pardon, but I have done lots of searching and I have found very little on the subject of using terminal commands for password encryption (other than `zip`). Believe me, I wouldn't waste people's time asking if I could already find the answer via google, or searching the stack forums. I have heard of p7zip, but i am wondering if there are any other options.

Comment: "stronger" "better" "recommend" - I'm not sure what you are needing. Stronger or better in what way in order to accomplish what?

Comment: the man for zip indicates it's not considered secure...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hdiutil` to create a compressed, encrypted disk image from a source folder like this:

```
hdiutil create -volname NameOfVolume \
    -srcfolder path/to/source/folder \
    -encryption AES-256 -ov -format UDZO name.dmg
```

For more options, see `man hdiutil` or poke around in the GUI for `hdiutil`, `DiskUtility`.